# Changing opacity for a div on scroll after being fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, opacity

I have a page containing divs of various heights (all same width). What I have done with them so far is set them to stick when the bottom of the div is reached when scrolling so that the next div appears to be scrolling up as the previous div remains fixed.

What I'm trying to do now is have it so that the previous div gradually fades while the page is being scrolled so that by the time the next div is scrolled to the top of the page, the previous div has completely disappeared. Likewise, I would like to have it so that when you scroll back up, the previous div gradually fades back in.

I have tried many solutions online which work for the first div on the page but all the other ones after it don't fade in or out correctly (or don't fade at all).

Here's what I have so far:

```
let windowHeight = $(window).height();
let sections = $(".page-section");

$(window).on("scroll", function () {
        sections.each(function () {
            var bounds = this.getBoundingClientRect();

                $(this).css({
                    opacity: ($(this).height() - $(window).scrollTop()) / $(this).height()
                })

            if (bounds.bottom <= windowHeight) {
                $(this).css({
                    position: "sticky",
                    top: bounds.top
                })
            }
        })
    })
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8Lux70bp/1/

As stated before this works for the first div but all the other ones after it have issues. I'm thinking it's due to their offset but I can't figure out how to incorporate that when scrolling.

Thanks

Comment: Please, provide a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example.

Comment: Please revert your question if my snippet is not applicable.

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/8Lux70bp/1/. Sorry, replied early. The first red div fades in and out okay but the green and blue ones fade out before I even reach them